# How to do two seperate actions with one submit form

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to do two actions on one form using a singular submit input. I am able to have the form populate in an email which is what I want but I would like to redirect to a confirmation page. I have looked at other inquiries on here and they do not seem to open a page. I see others able to anchor which is what I mainly tried and I have tried running jquery function within the ValidateForm() script but also does not open the page.

HTML

````
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="/js/Validate.js">

    </script>


    <style type="text/css">
  html, body{
    height: 100%;
  }

  body{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(/img/BpD6ruBXZqiH2Qvq4axJXZ.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <form name=”inputForm” onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" action="mailto:c.esteves@chcfl.org?Subject=Customer info" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
        Input First Name: <red>* required</red>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
        <input id="fnameID" type=”text” name=fName required="required"/>
    </div>
    </div>
          <br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
        Input Last Name: <red>* required</red>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-75">
        <input id="lnameID" type=”text” name=lName required="required"/>
          <br>
       </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
        Input Date before today: <red>* required</red>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-75">
        <input id="birthID" type=”date” name=birth placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" required="required"/>
          <br>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
        Input E-mail: <red>* required</red>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-75">
        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="name@domain.com" name=email required="required"/>
          <br>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
        Input Phone Number: <red>* required</red>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-75">
        <input id="phone" type="phone" placeholder="+1(555)555-5555" name=phone required="required"/>
          <br>
          </div>
    </div>
          <br>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
        Message: <br>
    </div>
        <div class="col-75">
        <textarea name=message id="message" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea> <br>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
        Security Question: <red>* required</red>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-75">
        <input id="verify" type=”text” name=verify placeholder="Dog talk and tree clothes?" required="required"/>
          <br>
          </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    </div>
          <a link href="http://www.analog-gamers.com/confirmationpage.html" ><input type="submit" value="send" name="submit"></a>
          <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset"/><br>
</div>
    </form>
</body>'''




```function ValidateForm(){
 var fName = document.getElementById("fnameID").value;
 if(!ValidateNotBlank(fName,"First Name")) return false;

var lName = document.getElementById("lnameID").value;
 if(!ValidateNotBlank(lName,"Last Name")) return false;

 var bDay = document.getElementById("birthID").value;
 if(!ValidateNotBlank(bDay,"Date")) return false;

var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
if(!ValidateNotBlank(email,"Email")) return false;

if(!ValidateEmail(email,"Email")) return false;

if(!ValidateDate()) return false;

var number1 = document.getElementById("phone").value;
if(!phoneLength(number1,"phone")) return false;

if(!securityQuestiony()) return false;

    return true;

}```
````

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do. From your code it looks like you're doing some validations and then call `verify()`, but we don't know what that does or when should the redirect occur. Do you want to redirect after the validations and if the user confirms, then redirect back and submit the data?

Comment: Verify is for a security question section not related to page redirection just wasnt sure if the format of Javascript helped with determining the proper syntax for the return portion of form on html. I changed it to reflect that sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Oh, so you want to both populate the email and redirect from the form while that's going on?

Comment: Correct. That is what I have been trying to do unsuccessfully.

Comment: Does the current code open the email on a separate tab? It should if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Oh ok, no worries. I was writing the same thing basically just now, good thing you pointed it out.

Comment: Yes it should and the fix i thought was it does not pass the information anymore. So page changed but not the onsubmit function no longer works

Comment: I've posted a solution. See if it suits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the `a` that wrap the `input`.

Now, I guess `function verify()` probably return more validation, so you just need to put in the final condition something like that:

```
if (validation is ok) { document.location.assign('http://www.analog-gamers.com/confirmationpage.html');}
else { show errors }
```

If this is not working, please share more code.

General example:

```html
<form name=”inputForm” onsubmit="return ValidateForm();" 
action="mailto:email@email.org?Subject=Customer info" method="post" 
enctype="text/plain">
.
.
.
.
<input type="submit" value="send" name="submit" />

</form>

<script>
function ValidateForm(){
.
.
.
.
/* if(!verify()) return false;
else  { */
document.location.assign('http://www.google.com'); // }  //yout URL

}
</script>
```

Comment: My apologies I updated code for JS as verify is not related to redirection.

Comment: On my answer i actually ignore it, did you try to implant it?

Comment: The logic is: after the function checked input and it is without errors then execute the line document.location.assign. If an error found the return will block the rest of the code for execute so delete the return true at the end and place the redirection. Since the action of the form is "mailto" the email applictaion will open (if there are no errors)...

Comment: Yes I did but I get the same response in that the email populates but no page redirection

Comment: This worked in firefox not chrom but i dont care thank you very much I feel silly that it was something that was so simple.

Comment: So the url now changes but now the information does no prompt the mailto

Comment: added more to the question. Also I tried without the return true at the end and just the document.location.assign... but it would just change pages and not mail the information to the email

Comment: That's  a lot code and still not whole. Anyway i guess something like that: if(!securityQuestiony()) {document.location.assign('http://www.analog-gamers.com/confirmationpage.html');};

Comment: Thank for your help I ended up doing the if(!securityQuestiony())   return false; 
    if(!securityQuestiony()){document.location.assign('analog-gamers.com/confirmationpage.html');} which worked. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to Confirmation page, you can add a redirect code inside your

> ValidateForm()

like this:

```js
ValidateForm(){
   e.preventDefault(); 
   window.location.replace("test.xyz");
   }
```

But remember this will cancel your original submit action.

Hope I got your question right.

Comment: That is the issue I am having as I would like to have information post to an email, as well as, redirect to new page. After dinking around with other JS functions I cant seem to make them work with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I have defined an a tag containing input without (type=submit) or out of form that can be successfully launched to the new site,so i guess the form submit button prohibits other click events added to the button.

Listening for submission event completeed and redirect to the new address using JS  is a way too.

Answer (score 0):

Add a short timer to the current `window` that redirects your page asynchronously.

```
function ValidateForm () {

    // whatever validations you need

    window.redirectTimer = setTimeout({
        window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    }, 250);

    if( !securityQuestion() ) return false;

    return true;
}
```

This will set up the redirection to happen in 250ms, tune it depending on your needs. The issue could be solved more efficiently with callbacks and whatnot, because using timers is sometimes frowned upon, but it would require more complex changes to your code, i.e. manually handling the data submission, not just by specifying the `action`.